# MDX / SSAS - Need flexible percent of parent measure

Tags: ssas, mdx, data-warehouse, cube, ssas-2008

I’ve been searching for hours on this and I’m just not adept enough at MDX to know if I’ve come across the solution yet. Everything I tried has not worked. The situation is, I need a “percent of parent” measure. In this example, the only thing I have gotten to work, each product code attribute displayed shows it’s sales as a percentage of every other product code attribute displayed:

```
([Product].[Product Code].CURRENTMEMBER,
[Measures].[Sales]) / ([Product].[Product Code].CURRENTMEMBER.PARENT,
[Measures].[Sales])
```

The problem is when the users start dragging other dimensions in or other attributes not in that hierarchy, or don’t use the product code attribute, it stops working and I get #NUM! values. Is there anyway to do a better percent of parent measure that’s more flexible? I really need something like a “percent of what’s visible” measure, ideally not dependent on a single dimension.

Comment: Can you provide an example of a full query?

Comment: They use Excel to manipulate the cube. I'm very much an MDX novice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unfortunately I can't provide a fully working example due to the lack of my laptop during my vacation :-)

What you're looking for can be achieved with the MDX functions AXIS and ITEM. Within this book

[http://www.amazon.com/Microsoft-Server-Analysis-Services-Cookbook/dp/1849681309/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1372255356&sr=8-1&keywords=tomislav+piasevoli](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849681309)

there is a dedicated chapter about "Context-Aware Calculations"

Hope this helps somehow

Tom